# What are some applications of modules, but not of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Some background: I'm taking Matrix Analysis, and my professor seems to think vector spaces are foundational to all of mathematics. What are some interesting applications from other areas of mathematics (or the outside world) that arise from modules, but are *not* applications of vector spaces?

Comment: It is less of an application than an equivalence, but abelian groups are the same things as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: Building on the comment by hardmath, the integral cohomology (which, for each degree, is an Abelian group, but not a vector space) of a smooth manifold is an object of importance in symplectic, algebraic, and complex geometry.  For example, it is a source of the (characteristic) Chern classes of complex vector bundles.

Comment: An enormous amount of classical linear algebra can be presented using modules over PIDs. Representations of groups are basically modules over group rings.

Answer (score 1):

You may be aware of the importance of the Jordan Normal Form of a matrix. If not you can google it and check the fact that every square matrix has a unique representation as the closest similar matrix to a diagonal matrix, is very useful for the resolutions of huge systems of equations. Well, in order to prove this, you can consider a vector space over a field k as a k[x]-module and use a battery of results of R-modules for a ring R.